# How to make a query that has a dynamic FROM clause to select a table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a database with several tables filled with parameters. I also have a table which lists the names of the tables that they show up in, their IDs (a number) and their names as they show up on a UI.
I have a separate table which lists all the parameters that are present in every table, the ID of the table that they are in, and also a name that the parameters have on a UI.

I'd like to make a query that based on user input translates the UI name to the database name, and queries a parameter from the selected table.

I tried a nested SELECT query, but the embedded query returns a table, not a string, so I couldn't use it as an input for my main query.

I also tried declaring a local variable, which would hold the result of the "translation" from the UI name to the database name. I am working with MariaDB, and got syntax errors when trying to declare, for which I couldn't find a solution.

Since I am not experienced with SQL, there might be more obvious or simpler solutions which I am missing. Please let me know if there is a different way I should approach this, or if you know the issue or mistake that I made in my attempts.

My nested query looked something like this:

```
SELECT 'parameter' 
FROM ( SELECT 'table_dbname' 
       FROM 'tables_dblist' 
       WHERE 'table_UIname' = userinput 
     ) AS tablequery
```

My attempt use a declared variable:

```
DECLARE @table_dbname as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @table_dbname = ( SELECT 'table_dbname' 
                      FROM 'table_dblist' 
                      WHERE 'table_UIname' = userinput 
                     )
```

userinput will be dealt with later, for the purpose of making the query work I just select one actual parameter and paste its name in the query manually for now.

Edit:
The db has tables: table1, table2, table_dblist, table_parameterlist
table1 has several columns: time, parameter1, parameter2,.. etc
table2 has some shared column names, while the rest is different: time, parameter1, parameter2.1, ... etc
table_dblist has 3 columns:

1. **tableID**: has an integer for each table, e.g. for table1 tableID is 1
2. **table_dbname**: the name of the table as it shows up in the database, e.g. table1
3. **table_UIname**: the name as it shows up on a UI, e.g. First Table

table_parameterlist has 3 columns as well:

1. **tableID**: the ID of the table in which the parameter is located, so shared parameter names can be differentiated
2. **parameter_dbname**: the name of the parameter column as it shows up in the db, e.g. parameter1
3. **parameter_UIname**: the name as it shows up on a UI, e.g. First Parameter

I will have a form in which users select a **table_UIname** and a **parameter_UIname** which is in that table. I'd like a query which would return the selected parameter from the specified table.
e.g. user selects Second Table and Third Parameter.
The more complex query's result I want to write would in this case be the same as:

```
SELECT parameter3 FROM table2
```

Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide sample datas, table description and expected result all in text format

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added more explanation and an example of what I am trying to achieve,

Comment: Regarding the declare route: based on answers to other similar issues I tried using delimiters, leaving out the DECLARE command, leaving out the @ prefix, but nothing seems to work, I still keep getting the same syntax error.